# SublimeText: bookmark a line using mouse?

Tags: mouse, sublimetext2

I am switching over to SublimeText 2 from Textmate.

In TextMate, a line can be bookmarked with the mouse by simply clicking the line number. I've been doing this for many years, and while I'm sure some people may prefer keyboard shortcuts, I'm not one of them.

Can I bookmark a line in Sublimetext using the mouse? Is there an option where this can be enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is only keyboard shortcut support. You can add mouse click feedback here http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19525-add-bookmarks-support/